# How to use bash variable in Azure CLI

Tags: bash, azure, jq, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am trying to use a bash variable (**ID in the below script**) in azure CLI command. but seems its not working and throwing below error:

> usage error `--scope`: must be a fully qualified ARM ID.

The error is happening on line `az policy assignment list --scope $ID`

I have verified by echoing the **ID variable** and its outputting correctly which is:

> "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/test-management-group"

**What i am doing wrong here?**

Full script is here:

```
MGS=$(az account management-group list)
for (( i = 0; i < ${#MGS[@]}; i++ )) 
do 
    ID=$(echo $MGS | jq .[$i].id)
    echo $ID
    az policy assignment list --scope $ID
done
```

Comment: Btw.: I suspect that `$MGS` is no array.

Comment: Invoke JQ with the **-r** option for a start.

Comment: @Cyrus its a json which i parsing using jq. length is returning correctly as well as the id property. that i can confirm.

Comment: @oguzismail -r is working. what is this -r. :). i would definitely check and thank you.

Comment: `MGS` is a *JSON* array, not a shell array. You need to iterate over the output of `jq '.[].id'`, something like `for ID in $(jq '.[].id'); do az policy assignment list --scope $ID; done`.

Comment: Does `az` support JMESPath expressions? You may not need to use `jq` or any shell iteration at all.

Comment: Without -r, JQ encodes strings as JSON strings and wraps double-quotes around them.

Comment: @oguzismail i would have know that before. Thanks man. much appreciated.

Comment: What's the latest news about your question? Do you solve it yourself or with my solution? Just give the updates.

Answer (score 0):

The suitable bash script example here:

```
for id in $(az account management-group list --query [].id -o tsv)
do
    echo "Management Group ID: $id"
    az policy assignment list --scope $id
done
```

Comment: i need the full arraylist and object from the query. its not about getting only the id by query. Anyway i have to use a -r after the jq to solve the issue. see comment from oguz ismail

Comment: @Rezoan Does you mean you already solve it yourself? Or you can give all the requirements, I can give the help if you need.

Comment: Thanks man. much appreciated. i have solved it.

Comment: @Rezoan Cheers to yourself！